# Is a question about software for automatic selection of photos using AI on topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm about to prepare albums for print and I have a huge number of photos to check (yes someone has no control over their shutter button).

I'd like to ask if there is a way to get some automated selection like on iOS, but for desktop. For example, a software using artificial intelligence to pick one image from each group of similar ones, taking into account sharpness, colours, faces and eyes open/closed, and so on.

It's kind of asking about selection for print, so on topic, but also clearly software recommendation related, so off topic.

Should I proceed or go to other sections of SE?

Comment: Trying to think where else if not here - There are AI image analysis utilities for the Raspberry Pi.  You may get advice on setting them up over there.

Comment: @Chenmunka There is https://ai.stackexchange.com/ but they don't want questions about already trained models: off topic are "asking for an API, library, or dataset (to solve a specific problem)" and "Questions seeking pre-trained models for a specific problem or problem domain"

Comment: The raspberry pi channel is for "Software specific to the Raspberry Pi". Also, I would not run that AI on a R-Pi, so a software specific to R-Pi would not suit my task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product recommendation questions generally aren't topical here. They were allowed (perhaps even encouraged?) during the site's infancy, but after a short time the site adopted the ["Q&A is hard. Let's go shopping!"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) philosophy common to most Stack Exchange sites, generally against product recommendations.

Sounds like your question is on-topic at [Software Recommendations](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). From their ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Help Center page:

> This site is for questions asking for recommendations of software ready-to-use to accomplish a particular task, that is, “what software can I use to do …?”. While this includes software libraries for development use, note that recommendations of tutorials, data sources, media libraries (e.g. icon collections) etc. are off-topic – as are questions like “what technology to use for …?”